# Code Analysis Failed (ERROR: org.jetbrains.kotlin.utils.KotlinExceptionWithAttachments: unexpected 2 declarations)

Tags: android-studio, error-handling, compiler-errors, code-analysis, jetbrains-ide

Does anybody know this error: Code analysis failed with exception: org.jetbrains.kotlin.utils.KotlinExceptionWithAttachments: unexpected 2 declarations ?

Thanks :D

Comment: Getting the same error when trying to commit